# Need to mention seperate wait for conditions in tosca

Tags: testing, automation, tosca

In Tosca default timeout I have mentioned is 35 seconds.So due to that the if condition taking whole 35secs to fails. Isthr way to mention seperate wait for condition alone.

Need to mention seperate wait for Tosca if condition

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a while loop including wait inside or outside the if statement..
[While loop with wait until the condition is met](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGUs3.png)

Comment: In general, the answer is good, but a better answer will include not only a link but also an example related to the question.